# Progress bar won't disappear when full screen

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fullscreen, html, opera

When I make a video full screen, progress bar (Red rectangle in picture) and mouse cursor are not getting lost. I checked in chrome, opera and microsoft edge browser only work in microsoft edge.In opera and chrome, youtube and openload are works but other players doesn't work.How can i solve this problem?

[progress bar (Red rectangle in picture) and mouse cursor are not getting lost.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5stO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have had this problem from long since I have watched Online Videos, And think i've finally solved it. Check for iframework.exe in your task manager and stop the task. Also try to remove it from the start up tasks through MSconfig. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a fix for mac, discovered this through trial and error, but if you exit out of your movie, hit fullscreen using the "green spot" (not the fullscreen toggle), then play your movie again and you won't get the problem.